# Fusing different laser scanners

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want implement a collision warning system based on 3 different laser scanners for a mobile robot. Hence I plan to fuse all scan messages in a new one that combines just measurements smaller than 80cm.

Now I define a new scan topic, with the smallest resolution of the 3 scanners and match the measurements on it. Is there a more smart solution for this problem?

Best wishes

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48175/fusing-different-laser-scanners/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, use a PointCloud2 for that.

Fusing different LaserScans is a really bad idea as a LaserScan message assumes distances around a central point in regular angles. You can't combine multiple lasers and still retain this.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4